# Collectors collect a list of pair in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I got a list of pairs that I want to sorted by the left field, I succeed to do it and to get the 25 first element but now the problem is that I want to collect the right element into a list (or even both of them) but I don't know how to do it there is a problem with the `toList()`.

```
return listOfTokens.stream()
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o1.getLeft().getCompare(terms.field.docCount),
                                           o2.getLeft().getTfIdf(terms.fielddocCount)))
        .limit(25)
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to collect just the right element, use `map` :

```
return listOfTokens.stream()
.sorted((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o1.getLeft().getCompare(terms.field.docCount), o2.getLeft().getTfIdf(terms.fielddocCount)))
        .limit(25)
        .map(o -> o.getRight())
.collect(toList());
```

If you want to collect both the right and left:

```
return listOfTokens.stream()
.sorted((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o1.getLeft().getCompare(terms.field.docCount), o2.getLeft().getTfIdf(terms.fielddocCount)))
        .limit(25)
        .flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.getLeft(),o.getRight()))
.collect(toList());
```

Comment: Also note that `.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.getLeft().getCompare(terms.field.docCount)))` is shorter.

Comment: the collect is still in red with that message: Error: java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: ...
    lower bounds: java.lang.String

Comment: My bad didn't change the return parameter